# Android killing sub process from c++ fails

Tags: android, c++, process, kill-process, multiprocess

My java code makes jni call to a c++ function (function0); the c++ code then starts a process:

```
int main_pid,new_process_pid=-1;
void function0(){
    main_pid=getpid();
    new_process_pid=fork();
    if(main_pid!=getpid()){
        main_process();//some process with its own threads
    }
}

void kill_sub_process(){
    if(new_process_pid!=-1){
        kill(new_process_pid,SIGKILL);
    }
}
```

when i try to kill the sub process by making a call from my activity onStop() to kill_sub_process function the following error shows up in logcat and the app crashes:

> Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1, fault addr 0x91cb3110 in tid 3844

what is the proper way to kill a sub process safely?

the process gets killed without any problems when i call the signal handler from inside the sub process but fails when the parent sends the signal;

Comment: Use a _"less agressive"_ signal, and have a signal handler in the subprocess that lets it terminate more gracefully and ordered.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ if you mean like SIGQUIT the sub process actually has a signal handler which terminates the process pretty gracefully, i've tried it; the same thing happens;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial and error i figured that the sub processes created by calling fork in c++ code can be killed in the java code by calling android.os.Process.killProcess(pid)( where pid is the the sub process id) but not by the parent c++ code;